# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) & TypeError: must be str, not MemberClass

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, dictionary

Below is my code for a class I am currently working.  The title contains the errors I am receiving.  Could someone please assist with my code? (The comment's explain the area of concern. Main Menu functions 5 & 6.)

#### PART 1 - CLASS ESTABLISHMENT

```
class MemberClass:
    name = ""
    phone = 0
    number = 0

    # Initiator Method
    def __init__(self, name, phone, number):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.number = number

    # Mutator Method 1
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # Mutator Method 2
    def set_phone(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone

    # Mutator Method 3
    def set_number(self, number):
        self.number = number

    # Accessor Method 1
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    # Accessor Method 2
    def get_phone(self):
        return self.phone

    # Accessor Method 3
    def get_number(self):
        return self.number

    # Display Method
    def display_data(self):
        print("")
        print("Current Team Member's Information")
        print("------------------------------------------------")
        print("Member's Name: ", self.name)
        print("Member's Phone Number: ", self.phone)
        print("Member's Jersey Number: ", self.number)
        print("------------------------------------------------")
```

#### PART 2 - PROGRAM FUNCTIONS AND DATA

```
# Create a function for the main menu

def print_menu():
    print("===========Main Menu===========")
    print("1. Display Current Team Roster.")
    print("2. Add Member.")
    print("3. Remove Member.")
    print("4. Edit Member.")
    print("5. Save Progress.")
    print("6. Load Current Team Roster")
    print("9. Exit Program.\n")
    return int(input("Please Enter Your Selection: "))

# Create a function for main menu option 1
def print_members(team_members):
    if len(team_members) == 0:
        print("No Current Team Members In Memory!  Please Add All Team Members.")

    else:
        for x in team_members.keys():
            team_members[x].display_data()

# Create a function for main menu option 2
def add_members(team_members):
    new_name = input("Enter New Team Member's Name: ")
    new_phone = int(input("Enter New Team Member's Phone Number: "))
    new_number = int(input("Enter New Team Member's Jersey Number: "))
    team_members[new_name] = MemberClass(new_name, new_phone, new_number)
    return team_members

# Create a function for main menu option 3
def remove_members(team_members):
    remove_name = input("Enter Existing Team Member's Name to Remove: ")
    if remove_name in team_members:
        del team_members[remove_name]
        print("The Team Member ("+remove_name+") Is No Longer In Our Roster.")

    else:
        print("The Provided Name ("+remove_name+") Is Not Currently In Our Roster.  Please Try Again.")

    return team_members

# Create a function for main menu option 4
def edit_members(team_members):
    original_name = input("Enter Existing Team Member's Name To Edit: ")
    if original_name in team_members:
        adjusted_name = input("Enter Existing Team Member's Updated Name: ")
        adjusted_phone = int(input("Enter Existing Team Member's Updated Phone Number: "))
        adjusted_number = int(input("Enter Existing Team Member's Updated Jersey Number: "))
        del team_members[original_name]
        team_members[original_name] = MemberClass(adjusted_name, adjusted_phone, adjusted_number)

    else:
        print("The Provided Name ("+original_name+") Is Not Currently In Our Roster.  Please Try Again.")

    return team_members

# Create a function for main menu option 5 ***PROBLEM AREA***
def save_members(members, filename):
    out_file = open(filename, "wt")
    with open(filename, "wt") as out_file:
        for name, phone, number in members.items():
            out_file.write(name + "," + phone + "," + number + "\n")

# Create a function for main menu option 6 ***PROBLEM AREA***
def load_members(members, filename):
    in_file = open(filename, "rt")
    with open(filename, "rt") as in_file:
        while True:
            in_line = in_file.readline()
            if not in_line:
                break
            in_line = in_line[:-1]
            name, phone, number = in_line.split(",")
            members[name] = phone
```

#### PART 3 - PROGRAM ROOT CODE

```
# Team manager welcome screen, date & time
print("Welcome to San Angelo's Softball Team Roster")
print("This program keeps the most up-to-date information")
print("Today's Date: April 23, 2018")
print("Current Time: 0900\n")

# Create a dictionary named "team_members"
team_members = {}

# Provides Menu Screen
menu_selection = print_menu()

# Create while loop repeating the main menu.
while menu_selection != 9:

    if menu_selection == 1:
        print_members(team_members)

    elif menu_selection == 2:
        team_members = add_members(team_members)

    elif menu_selection == 3:
        team_members = remove_members(team_members)

    elif menu_selection == 4:
        team_members = edit_members(team_members)

    elif menu_selection == 5:
        filename = input("Enter Desired Filename: ")
        save_members(team_members, filename)

    elif menu_selection == 6:
        filename = input("Enter Existing Filename: ")
        load_members(team_members, filename)

    menu_selection = print_menu()

print("Thank You For Updating San Angelo's Softball Team Roster!")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: In addition to the above, please also share the exact error (which includes the line and code that is erroring), and what the expected result is.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:/Users/mario/PycharmProjects/Week6Assignment/Team_Management_Part3.py", line 202, in <module>
        save_members(team_members, filename)

    File "C:/Users/mario/PycharmProjects/Week6Assignment/Team_Management_Part3.py", line 111, in save_members

        for name, phone, number in members.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: I am trying to get this to save the final result into a file (filename set by the user).  Above is the error I am receiving.  There are a total of 3 variables assigned to each person in the roster (name, phone, number).  The error is stating that I am one variable short.  Please assist. (Found in Part II of my program, specifically in the def save_members and def load_members sections)

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate a dictionary via `dict.items`, you may only iterate key / value pairs. Therefore, this line will fail as you are attempting to unpack 3 items when only 2 exist (key & value):

```
for name, phone, number in members.items():
```

Instead, what you *should* do:

```
for name, myclass in members.items():
    phone = myclass.phone
    number = myclass.number
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/mario/PycharmProjects/Week6Assignment/Team_Management_Part3.py", line 160, in <module>
    save_members(team_members, filename)

  File "C:/Users/mario/PycharmProjects/Week6Assignment/Team_Management_Part3.py", line 114, in save_members
    out_file.write(name + "," + phone + "," + number + "\n")

TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!  When applying the recommended update, I now get the above error.

Comment: Use `str(phone)` and `str(number)` instead of `phone` and `number`.

Comment: This is starting to work!! The script will save a file!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mario/PycharmProjects/Week6Assignment/Team_Management_Part3.py", line 147, in <module>
    print_members(team_members)
  File "C:/Users/mario/PycharmProjects/Week6Assignment/Team_Management_Part3.py", line 70, in print_members
    team_members[x].display_data()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'display_data'

Comment: This is the error I receive when attempting to load the saved file